# iPhone effect comment box

Tags: iphone, fadein, comments

I've just used Instagram application. I like the effect when I click on comment.
When you click "comment" you'll see a fade in view for insert the comment text.
How can I implement something like this?

Here two screenshot's:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a UIAnimation. Start the animation with the alpha of the view at 0, and then end the animation with the alpha of that view to 1, and commit the animation. And voila, you have a view that fades in.

It's easy. Create your view. When the user clicks the button, set the alpha of that view to 0 and set the size to smaller than your final size, etc.

lets say your view is called myView. you'd write:

> myView.alpha = 0;
>
> myView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);
>
> [self.view addSubVew: myView];
>
> [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Fade" context:nil];
>
> [UIView setAnimationDuration: .25];
>
> [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

and then you set the alpha to 1 and increase the size of the view

> myView.alpha = 1
>
> myView.frame = CGRectMake(25, 25, 200, 200);

and then you commit the animations

> [UIView commitAnimations];

It's something like that, i wrote it off the top of my head so I apologize for any syntax errors or anything. But that's pretty much how it's done.

Comment: I did :)
It looks like they do a fade in, and they also change the frame. It's still the same concept. You start the animation with how you want the view to look before the animation starts. Then start the animation, and then put the changes into it, on how you want the view to end up looking. Then commit the animation. Also, i forgot to add the subview, I've editted my code.

Comment: Try that new code. If you're using Interface Builder, make a UIView, and link it to myView. Then just set the background color for that view to something flashy, like red or something. And then run this code and see what the code does. When you see what's going on, play around with the code to get your desired results. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Fear, I hurt you if I say that I love you? Thanks man, that's amazing. :)

Comment: Fear, thank you for previous question. Can you try to click "like it" button in Instagram? The grey heart become red and it appears your username just above the "Like it" button. And this, how can I implement?

Comment: You're welcome. About the like it button, I see that the grey heart turns to red, but I don't see any usernames right above the like it button. The heart thing, it's easy. It is just two different images. For example, greyheart.PNG and redheart.PNG

when you click on the button, all it did was change the image from greyheart.PNG to redheart.PNG. It's very easy stuff, you use UIImage and you call myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redheart.PNG"]

Comment: make sure you add the images to your project using Xcode, first

Comment: Are you registered to Instagram? Try to click to random photo a click "like it".

Comment: Check the new screenshot above.